# Python commands not working in windows console

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I'm using python to create a django project. I need to use virtualenv, pip and django commands but when I execute them in console it gets frozen and don't send any output.

[image: Picture taken half an hour later]

I can't use this console any more and it makes two process in the Task Manager that are unkillable.

[image]

I've got Python 2.7 installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your encoding of the terminal is incorrect; this may be causing the problems. Try using PowerShell

Comment: Not working on powershell too

Comment: Try doing a basic `raw_input()` (with a prompt) then launch the script from Windows Explorer rather than cmd.  Does that work?  It could be your cmd shortcut is compromised in some way.  Has this *ever* worked on your machine?  if so, then what changed.

Comment: The python files executed like "python file_name.py" worked fine, the problem comes when I try to execute a command without the python command before, like pip or virtualenv. 

I've got this worked some time ago. I've installed Anaconda after that but I have it on my work too and doesn't gives me this problem.